# MongoDB and php in Ubuntu 11.04

Tags: php, ubuntu, mongodb

I have install **php** and then **mongodb** using aptitude. I wrote following program:

```
   <?php

$m = new Mongo();

$db = $m->selectDB("Employees");

?>
```

and i got following error

> PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Mongo' not found in /var/www/test.php on line 4

I saw my php version it is:

**PHP 5.3.5-1ubuntu7.2 with Suhosin-Patch (cli) (built: May  2 2011 23:18:30)**

Can anybody tell me why this problem is coming?

Answer (score 6):

The PHP MongoDB is obviously not installed.

See [MongoDB](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/PHP+Language+Center)

Comment: I did exactly those steps, and i am getting that error. while i done those steps on my mac mini it works fine.

Comment: finally I got the answer. In ubuntu put your "mongo.so" file in /etc/php5/cli/php.ini.

Comment: Note: For apache, the file is at /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini

Answer (score 4):

You have not installed MongoDB PHP driver please see this link http://www.php.net/manual/en/mongo.installation.php

Install MongoDB PHP Driver

```
sudo apt-get install php5-dev php5-cli php-pear
sudo pecl install mongo
```

Open your php.ini file and add to it:

```
extension=mongo.so
```

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you have apache2 and PHP5+ installed in your server:

```
sudo apt-get install apache2 php5 libapache2-mod-php5
```

Install some dependencies for the driver:

```
sudo apt-get install php-pear php5-dev
```

And install it: `sudo pecl install mongo`

Now, let's hack that php.ini too, located at /etc/php5/apache2/ path. Do that by adding mongo.so extension somewhere after the extensions part:

```
sudo vim /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini
Add : extension = mongo.so
```

Then restart apache server :

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Answer (score 0):

Install MongoDB PHP Driver:

> sudo apt-get install php5-dev php5-cli php-pear
>   
>   sudo pecl install mongo

Install php5-mongo Pacakge:

> sudo apt-get install php5-mongo

Open your php.ini file and add to it:

> extension=mongo.so

Comment: apt-get install php5-mongo gets you an ubuntu package (.deb) with an older version while pecl install will get you a pecl package with a more recent version (in ubuntu 14.10 at least). But they both install the end lib mongo.so, so doing both will break one of them (working for my necromancer's badge (: )